# How can I restore the default dimensions of the Force Quit dialog

Tags: defaults, display, dialog

I accidentally maximized the Force Quit dialoge on my Mac and I am looking for a way to restore it to its original size other than manually resizing it. I would like it to be have exact dimensions as before.

Is there such a way to do that, for example, with preference files or `defaults`?

Comment: If you tell us how did you minimze it in first place ?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete a key in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist:

```
defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow 'NSWindow Frame ProcessPanel'
```

The changes seem to be applied immediately.

Answer (score -1):

simply double click on the taskbar. that will do the trick :)